# Its possible to keep local storage in development after app hot-reload?

Tags: angular

I have a `token.guard.ts` that check token is valid. If the user don't have a token will be redirect to the login page. This is fine for production, but for development is a big spend of time, because every hot reload angular clear the local storage and I need to put my credentials again.

How I can preserve my local storage between hot-reloads?

Comment: local storage remains as is even after reload. Are you sure you are not clearing local storage at application start up in code?

Comment: it 's look like you are clear the local stoarge when the app is run 